# how to implement the vertical alignment when changing <div> block size

Tags: html, css, alignment, vertical-alignment

How to implement the vertical alignment when changing `<div>` block size (in my example - green blocks).

What needs to change in my example, that when the browser window is resized happened vertical alignment (middle) side blocks.

`vertical-align: middle` or `top : calc(50% - 25px)` properties does not work.

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vsdu0cn8

My case and what need
[image: screenshot]
<sub>(source: [imageup.ru](http://www.imageup.ru/img41/2396110/example.png))</sub>

Code:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
        font-size: 0px;
      }

      .menu-block {
        max-width: calc(2 * 75px + 7 * (50px + 2 * 5px));
        background-color: #ff8080;
      }

      .menu-block .menu-edge {
        display: inline-block;
        position: relative;
        left: 0px;
        width: 75px;
        height: 50px;
        vertical-align: top;
        background-color: #80ff80;
      }

      .menu-block .menu-container {
        display: inline-block;
        width: calc(100% - 2 * 75px);
        text-align: center;
        background-color: #ff80ff;
      }

      .menu-block .menu-container .menu-element {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        margin: 0px 5px;
        font-size: 20px;
        background-color: #ffff80;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='menu-block'>
      <div class='menu-edge'></div>
      <div class='menu-container'>
        <div class='menu-element'>#1</div>
        <div class='menu-element'>#2</div>
        <div class='menu-element'>#3</div>
        <div class='menu-element'>#4</div>
        <div class='menu-element'>#5</div>
        <div class='menu-element'>#6</div>
        <div class='menu-element'>#7</div>
      </div>
      <div class='menu-edge'></div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why not use `display: flex;` and align the content of the sideblock in the center?

Comment: Sorry but I am unable to understand what you want. Can you please be more descriptive or provide an image for illustrating what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by setting the container with `display:flex` you can use   `align-items: center` in order to center your text verticaly.

Please see the updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oronbdd/vsdu0cn8/3/):

HTML:

```
<div class = 'menu-block'>
    <div style="display:flex; align-items: center">
    <div class = 'menu-edge'></div>
    <div class = 'menu-container'>
      <div class = 'menu-element'>#1</div>
      <div class = 'menu-element'>#2</div>
      <div class = 'menu-element'>#3</div>
      <div class = 'menu-element'>#4</div>
      <div class = 'menu-element'>#5</div>
      <div class = 'menu-element'>#6</div>
      <div class = 'menu-element'>#7</div>
    </div>
    <div class = 'menu-edge'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but your example is not working - when I change the size of the browser window, then yellow blocks (1..7) are not arranged in several rows, and green blocks - not aligned vertically

Comment: Hi, you asked about vertial alignment, I thought that you are talking about the centring the text. please try to be more specific with your request. I still dont understand...

Comment: Hi, I've updated my previous solution, please check the updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oronbdd/vsdu0cn8/2/

Comment: Oron Ben-David

Look at my example http://imageup.ru/img41/2396110/example.png
In your case - green block on top.
And I need - to green the block was in the middle

Comment: sorry, copied the wrong url, this is the updated one: http://jsfiddle.net/oronbdd/vsdu0cn8/3/

Comment: Oron Ben-David, it's cool.

Please tell me, is it possible to implement the example # 2, instead of the example # 1, provided that, as in example # 1, the width of the window is not strictly defined by

http://www.imageup.ru/img107/2397121/example.jpg